# What is a clustered index query in SQL Server ? How it differ from normal SQL query?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I heard about clustered query from my friend.

I just want to know about what is **clustered query**, and how does it differ from a normal SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have related queries within a session this method will attempt to relate them to your session data to allow for more efficient searches.

Source : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_query_classification

Comment: yeah,i want to know why we are going for clustering?